# Scala - understanding a code snippet involving currying

Tags: scala

I'm new to scala and I'm having a little trouble understanding currying - I'm practicing by coding simple functions for now, and would need clarification about the following

```
 def mul (a: Int) (b: Int): Int =
  {
  {
  a * b
  }
  }
```

Is the above function definition same as the below?

```
def mul: Int => Int => Int = {
  (a: Int) =>
    {
      (b: Int) =>
        a * b
    }
}
```

From syntax I could interpret `mul` as a function that accepts an integer, and returns a function that accepts an integer and returns an integer. But I'm not sure if my interpretation is actually correct. Any explanation regarding the above example or the syntax of curried functions will be really helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct.  But you don't need all those braces.

```
def mul(a: Int)(b: Int) = a*b

val mulAB = (a: Int) => { (b: Int) => a*b }   // Same as mul _
val mul5B = (b: Int) => 5*b                   // Same as mulAb(5) or mul(5) _
```

In general, you can rewrite any function with multiple arguments as a curried chain instead, where each argument produces a function that takes one fewer arguments until the last one actually produces the value:

```
f(a: A ,b: B ,c: C, d: D): E  <===>  A => B => C => D => E
```

In Scala, the natural grouping is by *parameter block*, not by individual parameter, so

```
f(a: A)(b: B, c: C)(d: D): E  <===>  A => (B,C) => D => E
```

Comment: +1, and it might be nice to add that you can not only rewrite any function, but Scala already provides the `curried` method on functions for that.